# Print in c# with specific options

Tags: wpf, printing

I am wondering if it is possible to print a few images with specific options in c#.
We have bunch of images in our db.
The options also will be coming from db.
For ex: 
Option 1: FileName1, A3 Size, Landscape, Print Quality = Best, Pages persheet = 1, 600 DPI, whole page.
Will appreciate any input.
Thanks,
N

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Use PrintTicket, for example:

```
  PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
  if(printDialog.ShowDialog()==true)
  {
    PrintTicket ticket = new PrintTicket();
    ticket.PageOrientation = MyDocument.PaperSize.PageOrientation;
    ticket.PageMediaSize = MyDocument.PaperSize.PageMediaSize;

    XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printDialog.PrintQueue);
    writer.WritingPrintTicketRequired += (s, printTicketEvent) => { printTicketEvent.CurrentPrintTicket = ticket; };
    MyDocument.PrintTo(writer);
  }
```

You can also set the PrintTicket more directly and not use the event, but I had some trouble with driver compatibility that caused me to do it this way instead.

Comment: What is the type of MyDocument in this example?